# How can I generate a .vue file inside my vue folder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I used the vue-auto-routing for my routes. My concern is how can I generate a .vue file instead of manually creating a file inside the pages folder. My goal here is to have a function like a CMS that generates a page automatically.

Comment: why have you tagged vue2 AND vue3 - you would never use both at the same time

Comment: `how can I generate a .vue file` generate from what? `generates a page automatically` - what are the input parameters for this page generator?